# Split string and add to array list

Tags: java, android, string, list, tree

I have a sorted list of Strings, that I need to split and add it to a Tree or some kind of list. For example, if I have these strings:

```
    List<String> folders = new ArrayList<String>();
    folders.add("Buffet::soups::veg soup");
    folders.add("Buffet::soups::non veg soup");
    folders.add("Buffet::soups::non veg soup::chicken soup");
    folders.add("Vegetables");
    folders.add("Cheese");
    folders.add("Buffet::Starters");
    folders.add("Buffet::Sandwitch");
    folders.add("Buffet::Sandwitch::Cheese Sandwitch");
    folders.add("Buffet::soups::veg soup::tomato soup");
```

So that I can have a Category and subcategories associated with that category in a list or a tree.
Any help would be much-appreciated thanks.

Comment: why you just dont define a class model for that instead of working with strings?

Comment: I need to split the string so that I can differentiate between category and sub category.

Answer (score 1):

use a class to define a category/subcategory and another to define a product.
your category is an object containing a list of categories and a list of products.

```
public class Category {

    private String name;
    private List<Category> subCategories;
    private List<Product> products;

    // getter/setters
}

public class Product {
    private String name;
    // any other property defining your product

    // getters/setters
}
```

with this you can build a tree. use a Factory; an utility class or even the builder of your category object (but that's dirty) to build your tree.

then pass your String to the Utility class to add it to your tree

```
public class ProductTreeBuilder {

    public static Category addToTree(Category mainNode, String toAdd) {
        if (mainNode == null) {
            mainNode = new Category("BaseCategory");
        }
        Category currentNode = mainNode;
        String[] path = toAdd.split("::");
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {

            String nameCatOrProduct = path[i];
            // if end of path, it's a produc
            // if it's not in product list, add it
            if ((i == path.length - 1) && !currentNode.getProducts().contains(nameCatOrProduct)) {
                currentNode.getProducts().add(new Product(nameCatOrProduct));
            } else {
                // check if currentNode contains subCategory
                Category subCategory = currentNode.getSubCategories().stream().filter(c -> c.getName().equals(
                        nameCatOrProduct)).findFirst().orElse(null);
                if (subCategory == null) {
                    // subCategory doesn't exist yet, create it
                    subCategory = new Category(nameCatOrProduct);
                    currentNode.getSubCategories().add(subCategory);
                }
                // continue with the subCaegory
                currentNode = subCategory;
            }
        }

        return mainNode;

    }
}
```

then you can simply use your factory to build your tree:

```
    Category tree = null;
    tree = ProductTreeBuilder.addToTree(tree, "cat1::cat2::test");
    tree = ProductTreeBuilder.addToTree(tree, "cat2::test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a Category

```
class Category
{
    private String name = "";
    private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>();
    private Category parent = null;
    public Category(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void addChild(Category child)
    {
        child.parent = this;
        children.add(child);
    }
    public Collection<Category> children()
    {
        return new HashSet<>(children);
    }
    public Category parent()
    {
        return parent;
    }
    public String toString(){return name;}
    public String entireHierarchyToString()
    {
        return entireHierarchyToString(0);
    }
    private String entireHierarchyToString(int d)
    {
        String tmp = "";
        for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
            tmp += "\t";
        tmp += name;
        for(Category c : children)
            tmp += "\n" + c.entireHierarchyToString(d+1);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Then we use a recursive method to build the tree for us:

```
private void process(String[] path, int p, Category root)
{
    if(p >= path.length)
        return;
    String tmp = path[p];
    Category next = null;
    for(Category c : root.children()) {
        if (c.toString().equals(tmp)) {
            next = c;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(next == null) {
        next = new Category(tmp);
        root.addChild(next);
    }
    process(path, p+1, next);
}
```

In our main method we can then use the following logic:

```
 List<String> folders = new ArrayList<String>();
 folders.add("Buffet:soups:veg soup");
 folders.add("Buffet:soups:non veg soup");
 folders.add("Buffet:soups:non veg soup:chicken soup");
 folders.add("Vegetables");
 folders.add("Cheese");
 folders.add("Buffet:Starters");
 folders.add("Buffet:Sandwitch");
 folders.add("Buffet:Sandwitch:Cheese Sandwitch");
 folders.add("Buffet:soups:veg soup:tomato soup");

 Category root = new Category("[ROOT]");
 for(String s : folders)
 {
      process(s.split(":"), 0, root);
 }
 System.out.println(root.entireHierarchyToString());
```

This should print out:

```
[ROOT]
    Buffet
        soups
            veg soup
                tomato soup
            non veg soup
                chicken soup
        Starters
        Sandwitch
            Cheese Sandwitch
    Vegetables
    Cheese
```